# Android Architecture Components ( Android Jetpack ) breaks Instant Apps

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I have an android project that supports instant apps.
So, I have these in the `base feature`

```
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
api 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1"
```

when I have these the

```
installable app
```

doesn't launch with the following error

> Default activity not found

When I remove

```
api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1"
```

the

```
installable app
```

doesn't give errors, but of course I'm missing a direct dependency here, so it doesn't build.

I have tried every version of the support library alongside every version and module of the new architecture components, I even tried using

```
implementation
```

instead of

```
api
```

but nothing works.

It appears as if the architecture components break instant apps.

Also here are the dependencies.

```
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |         +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |         |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |         +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |         |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |         \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    \--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0-alpha1
|         +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|         \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0
|    \--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.0
\--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1
     +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0-alpha1
     |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.0.0-alpha1
     |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.0.0-alpha1
     |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
     \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
```

Comment: why are you posting here? Looks like a bug report rather than a question. Try on the google issue tracker for android

Comment: I thought someone would know a workaround. Which repository should I create the issue in?